# What are the all equivalence classes that exist for this relation?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Let $f$ be a function that associates a set of $n$ points $P\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with a graph $G$ in the following way:

If $S$ is the set of all line segments between each possible pair of points in $P$, then $G$ is the graph whose nodes represent the line segments in $S$ and whose edges represent their intersections. In other words, two line segments in $S$ are adjacent in graph $G$ if they are intersecting. Also assume that no subset of $P$ with cardinality greater than 2 is colinear.

Then let $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $P\sim Q$ if and only if the graphs $f(P)$ and $f(Q)$ are isomorphic (where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set).

Then, for any given value of $n$, how can I identify each (or at least find the number of), equivalence classes for $\sim$?

---

It is at least intuitive for me that, and I am fairly certain that, when $P$ can be taken as the vertices of a convex polygon, this should represent a unique equivalence class.

However, I am unsure of where to go from there.

Comment: Are two line segments which share a vertex in $P$ considered to "intersect"?

Comment: @hardmath No. My bad, I should have clarified that.

Comment: Also, note that for $n\ge 6$ your second idea doesn't hold.  A pair of diagonals in a convex hexagon may fail to intersect wthout sharing an endpoint.

Comment: @hardmath Oops, yeah I can see that now. Again, my bad. But I'm still pretty certain that it will correspond to a unique equivalence class, even if I can't think of how to prove it right now.

Comment: One can certainly think about which points of $P$ form the convex hull, and if all of them do, then that gives us one graph isomorphism class.  Doing some small values of $n$ will probably give further insight.  E.g. for $n=4$ having one point inside a triangle gives six independent (isolated) nodes (line segments), while putting all four on the convex hull admits a maximal independent set of five nodes.  So there are those two classes.

Comment: Your construction is that of the [intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) for open line segments between each pair of points in $P$.  By itself this doesn't give much information as every graph can be realized as an intersection graph, but your problem may have been studied in the literature.  It's worth doing a bit more research on that angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We begin by counting the nodes of the [intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) of open line segments between all pairs of points $u,v \in P$.  Since there are $n = |P|$ (non-collinear) points in the plane, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ open line segments that form the nodes of graph $\mathscr G$.

It is easy to give a sharp upper bound on the number of edges in $\mathscr G$.  Two nodes are connected by an edge if and only if their corresponding open line segments intersect, and this occurs if and only if their endpoints form a convex quadrilateral when taken in alternating order:

[image: convex quadrilateral on left, non-convex on right]

(Credit [Gareth Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68063/gareth-rees) for image at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981450/487781))

Since each set of four points in $P$ produces an edge in $\mathscr G$ (consisting of two intersecting diagonals) if and only if the corresponding quadrilateral is convex, graph $\mathscr G$ has at most $\binom{n}{4}$ edges. That many occur exactly when all our potential quadrilaterals are convex.  A little thought reveals this to be so precisely when the points $P$ form a convex $n$-gon.

This leads nicely into a proof that two convex $n$-gons $P,P'$ will give isomorphic intersection graphs $\mathscr G, \mathscr G'$.  Order consecutively the points $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ around $P$ and the points $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ around $P'$.  The points correspondence between $u_i$ and $v_i$ induces a consistent correspondence between the open line segments of $P$ and of $P'$.  Thus we have a mapping of nodes in $\mathscr G$ to nodes in $\mathscr G'$.

Finally the consistent ordering of points around each convex polygon ensures that a convex quadrilateral, composed of alternating endpoints of two segments in $P$, corresponds to a convex quadrilateral whose diagonals are intersecting open segments in $P'$.  Therefore the edges of $G$ map to edges of $G'$ under the induced correspondence of nodes, and conversely.  The two intersection graphs are isomorphic.

The analysis of cases where points of $P$ lie strictly inside its convex hull seems a daunting project.  One possible approach is to consider nesting of convex hulls, or [convex layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers).  For now it seems feasible only to work through some instances with very modest numbers of these interior points, hoping to account for additional graph isomorphism classes.

Comment: It may be interesting to the Reader to work out the nodes' degrees for $\mathscr G$ in the convex $n$-gon case.  Let the points in $P$ be consecutively numbered $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ as above.  Then segment $\overline{u_j u_n}$ intersects $\overline{u_i u_k}$ if and only if $1\le i \lt j \lt k \lt n$.